# How do I use the bootstrap icon package in angular

Tags: html, css, asp.net, angular, typescript

I downloaded the bootstrap icon and font awesome packages. But I don't know how to use it, I just imported the following into styles.css file : `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"; @import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";`

I guess I need to add something in the angular.json file, but I'm typing the path incorrectly [image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ npm i bootstrap-icons
```

And add follow line to style.css file:

```
@import "~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
```

And use icons like that(just example):

```
<i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
```

You can find any icons you would like to use in follow bootstrap official docs: [bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try after removeing `./`.
like :

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
],
```

Comment: Do I have to add it to style.css after adding it like this?

Comment: No, once you add it here! that should be it. No need to add it to style.css

Comment: I have added to angular.json but when I don't add to style.css the icons are not visible

Comment: looks like there is angular font awesome library which can be use: https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome